# Make header transition smoother when scrolling up

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I created a header, added a scroll-up effect, and changed its color. So it is transparent when on top, hidden when scrolling down and white & sticky when scrolling up.

What I want to achieve is a `smoother transition from white to top transparent` when scrolling up. Tried to add transition CSS variations, but not working.

Here is how it looks when scrolling to the top. the white turns transparent instantly. I want to add a smoother transition.

[image: smoother transition]

Any suggestions? Here is the code that I added to make it sticky:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
if (mypos > 40) {
if(mywindow.scrollTop() > mypos) {
$('#transparentsticky').addClass('headerup');
} else {
$('#transparentsticky').removeClass('headerup');
}
}
mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
}); }); });
```

```css
#transparentsticky{
-webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
transition : margin 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
.headerup{
margin-top: -150px !important; /*adjust this value to the height of your header*/
}
```

I also added this code to the Header section which adds the white transition ( white header appearing) Maybe something can be added here to make it smoothly fade into transparent as well?

```
.elementor-sticky--effects {
   background: #ffffff!important; /* change the background color here*/
 transition: .3s all ease-in-out!important;
}

.elementor-sticky--effects .sticky-menu-items ul li a /* change the menu text color here*/ {
   color: #fff!important;
}
.elementor-sticky--effects, .sticky-menu-items ul li a {
  transition: .3s all ease-in-out;
}

/* HIDES THE DARK LOGO */
.d-logo {
 display: none;
}
/* SWITCHES LOGO ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects .d-logo {
 display: inline-block;
}
.elementor-sticky--effects .l-logo {
 display: none;
}

/* CHANGES THE MENU COLOR ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects  .sticky-menu-items ul li a  {
 color: #000000!important;
}
/*Change the search icon color on scroll*/
.elementor-sticky--effects  .search-on-scroll i  {
 color: #000000!important;
}
/*Change the hamburger icon color on scroll*/
.elementor-sticky--effects  .hamburgericon i  {
 color: #000000!important;
}
/*Change the cart icon color on scroll*/
.elementor-sticky--effects  .menucart i  {
 color: #000000!important;
}

/* CONTROLS THE TRANSITION SPEED - KEEP ALL SAME SPEED TO HAVE A CLEAN EFFECT */
.elementor-sticky--effects .sticky-menu-items ul li a {
 transition: .3s all ease-in-out!important;
}
.elementor-sticky--effects {
 transition: .3s all ease-in-out!important;
}

/*change color to the mobile menu toggle*/
.elementor-sticky--effects .sticky-menu-items i {
 color: #000000/*add your color here*/!important;
}


/* CHANGES THE TEXT HOVER COLOR ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects .sticky-menu-items ul li a:hover {
 color: #3F525F/*add your color here*/!important; /* edit here to change your text color for sticky header */
}
/* CHANGES THE SEARCH HOVER COLOR ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects .search-on-scroll i:hover {
 color: #3F525F/*add your color here*/!important; /* edit here to change your text color for sticky header */
}

/* CHANGES THE HAMBURGER HOVER COLOR ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects .hamburgericon i:hover {
 color: #3F525F/*add your color here*/!important; /* edit here to change your text color for sticky header */
}
/* CHANGES THE CART HOVER COLOR ON SCROLL */
.elementor-sticky--effects .menucart i:hover {
 color: #3F525F/*add your color here*/!important; /* edit here to change your text color for sticky header */
}
```

Comment: `ease in out` is invalid, maybey ou meant `ease-in-out`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: However, it does not solve this. Any suggestions on how to achieve a smoother transition when scrolling to the top?